# Using wrong WebSocket protocol returns an "unexpected EOF" error in gorilla/websocket/client.go's Dial function

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I was trying to connect to a server in Go by using [gorilla/websocket](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket)
and I kept getting the error "unexpected EOF". It took me way too long to find out it was because I needed to use the secure WebSocket protocol to connect to that server ("wss://" instead of "ws://" in my url).

How can I verify that I'm using the wrong protocol for a given endpoint so that I can log a helpful error message instead of "unexpected EOF"?

Comment: Did you specify a port number in the URL? If not, the error is with the server. It should have either refused the connection on port 80, or returned an HTTP response describing the issue.

Comment: I did specify the port in the URL, but when I debug inside the Dial function, I notice that the server response is nil at some point and that's where the error occurs.

Comment: Don't include the port if it's :443.   The [call to http.ReadResponse](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/c908dc801cef474e686e478694c8f9f32e233901/client.go#L348-L351) is probably returning `nil, io.UnexpectedEOF` because the server is closing the connection because of missing TLS handshake.